# Changing colours of items in an array, javasccript program

Tags: javascript

I have written a JavaScript program which prints out a calendar for any year. It then prints family birthdays on appropriate dates using the coding below:

```
for(vari = 0; row = content.rows[i]; i++){
row = content.rows[i];
for (var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++){
    if (col.firstChild.nodeValue == 10
    col.firstChildnodeValue = birthdays[0]

and so on.
{
{
```

Details and dates of the birthdays are stored in an array. I wish to print the birthday dates and details in red on the calendar.

Comment: Does this help? it show how to apply color http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `span` tag with `.style.color = "red";`
For example :

```
var spanToCreate = document.createElement("span"); //This creates a <span>
spanToCreate.style.color = "red"; //Change he's writing color
document.appendChild(spanToCreate); //Puts him in the <body> tag and makes it become a valid <span> tag
```